# Using the last element of a list as the item for a for-loop

Tags: python, arrays

Sorry for the cumbersome worded question, but given the following array:

```
x = [1,2,3,4]
```

When I loop through it using the first index with the following loop:

```
for x[0] in x:
    print(x)
```

I get the following expected result:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[2, 2, 3, 4]
[3, 2, 3, 4]
[4, 2, 3, 4]
```

However, when I execute the following loop using the last index of `x`:

```
for x[-1] in x:
    print(x)
```

I would expect to get the following, call it 'result 1' (My current thought process is that for each iteration, the value of the current iteration replaces the last element of `x`):

```
[1, 2, 3, 1]
[1, 2, 3, 2]
[1, 2, 3, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

But instead, I get this, call it 'result 2':

```
[1, 2, 3, 1]
[1, 2, 3, 2]
[1, 2, 3, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 3]
```

Can someone explain why I am getting 'result 2'? I don't understand why I am getting 'result 2' instead of 'result 1'?

EDIT: Sorry `nums` was suppose to be called `x`.

Comment: How does `for x[0] in x` relate to `nums`?

Comment: Something seems to be missing here. What is the relationship between `nums` and `x` ?

Comment: First off, you should call `nums` `x` because thats what you say it is.

Comment: You're modifying `x`.  The third time through the loop, x = [1, 2, 3, 3], so the fourth time through the loop, x[-1] gets assigned three again.

Comment: "for" doesn't create a copy of the list it iterates through. When it retrieves the last item in 4th iteration it gets the value that was set already in 3rd iteration.

Comment: @FrankYellin nailed it.  After the first loop, the value `4` no longer exists in your list.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. As for me using `x[0]` or `x[-1]` in `for`-loop is wrong idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop is effectively equivalent to:

```
x[3] = x[0]
print(x)
x[3] = x[1]
print(x)
x[3] = x[2]
print(x)
x[3] = x[3]
print(x)
```

The last iteration doesn't change anything, since it's assigning an element to itself.

To get your expected results, you can do:

```
for x[0] in x[:]:
    print(x)
```

`x[:]` makes a copy of `x`, so you're not modifying the same list you're iterating over.

Answer (score 0):

`for x[-1] in x:` assigns the iterated values to the last element of the list, in turn. By the time you iterate that last value, you've already changed it to '3`, so that's what you get.